# screen scraping internal web site for content owners using coldfusion

Tags: regex, coldfusion, screen-scraping

First of all, this is a legit request.  I need to obtain the ower ids for web sites on our intranet.  There are about 3000 people I need to look up so instead of manually clicking on each site and seeing the id, copy and paste into my excel worksheet, I thought I'd just loop over the list (which I already have) and screen scrape the owenr id.  I thought I'd build a cf page that would go get the pages and store the resulting content into a database.  What I'd like to do though is remove everything else from teh returned page and retain only the Owner ID value.  In the code below, the value I'm looking for is tb1245.  This is the resulting content returned:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Site/Folder Name:</td>
    <td>AppliedScien<td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Vanity URL:</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Owner ID:</td>
    <td>tb1245
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Owner Name:</td>

            <td>
                <a style="font-family: ariel">Tom W&nbsp;BEST&nbsp;(tb1245)&nbsp;</a>
                <a style="font-family: 'Wingdings'; font-size: 12pt; color: blue;" href="mailto:tb1245@us.domain.com">*</a>&nbsp;
                <a style="font-family: 'Wingdings'; font-size: 12pt; color: blue;" href="javascript:webPhone('tb1245')">(</a>
            </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Web/Server Admin:</td>
        <td>

                    <a style="font-family: ariel">Ohtro J&nbsp;Pepper&nbsp;(tc6139)&nbsp;</a>
                    <a style="font-family: 'Wingdings'; font-size: 12pt; color: blue;" href="mailto:ot9533@swmail.domain.com">*</a>&nbsp;
                    <a style="font-family: 'Wingdings'; font-size: 12pt; color: blue;" href="javascript:phonebook('ot9533')">(</a>

        </td>
    </tr>
```

Can someone help me with this?  I'm supposed to have it completed by Friday but man is this mindnumbing work so I'd rather do it through coldfusion and impress my boss.  :D

TIA

Comment: There is a missing <td> after the user id of tb1245.  This was not omitted in my post, it isn't there in the original html code.  I double checked.  :D

Comment: Rather than screen scraping 3000 pages from your own internet, isn't this data somewhere in a DB you can get a report from?

Comment: There is but the request approval process takes too long.  Its their way of saying, "We'll make you jump through so many hoops and drag our feet on this in hopes that you will lose interest".    Seriously.

Comment: Make sure you pass in the parameter to up your request timeout so that the CF processing does not time out.

Comment: *request approval process takes too long* `<cfsetting requestApprovalProcessTime="60sec">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So assuming you've got your list of 3000 URLs that you're looping over.  For each one of those:

Use CFHTTP to get the content.  It's returned in cfhttp.fileContent.

You need to then parse this using a regex to extract that ID.  This worked for me with your content:

```
<cfoutput>
ID: #reReplaceNoCase(cfhttp.fileContent, ".*<tr>\s*<td>Owner ID:</td>\s*<td>([a-z0-9]+)\s*</tr>.*", "\1")#
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: This worked great!  I did change it up some by removing additional characters to make returned results small but this answer answers my OP perfectly.  Thank you.